# use both height and min height, and both in percent

Tags: css, height

Is there a way to set min-height based on percent in CSS ?

when I have used both height and min-height, I can't use both in percent I'm looking for a way to control min-height because my content is based on percent and the height of it changed.

I can't set the height to auto, because I need the height to be 100% and min-height is also based on percent.

that is the design of page, It shoud be full screen , until the minimun-height, but in a range of 1400 to 1100 the page is responsive and get smaller by percent, and I wanna keep those ratio, I mean height 100% until the minimun specific height, but becuase my content height changing I want that specific minimun height is also change

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
.outer {
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    /* MIN-HEIGHT ???????!!! */
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    background:blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 30%;
}
```

Here is the fiddle of my PROBLEM , http://jsfiddle.net/LmDNx/1/

as you can see I want to set the min hight for the outer div as the size of inner div, but the inner div is based on percent and also height is 100%, what can min-height be ??

**UPDATE : you can omit that position absolute**

Comment: no. I want the height is 100% and cover all the window, actulay I want height is 100% and the min-height change base on inner div not the size of the window

Comment: Normally height 100% and when shrunk the height shouldn't get lesser than inner div height?

Comment: yesss that's what I want, the height 100% but when resize verticaly the page the height cant get lesse that inner div

Comment: How tall can the `.inner` div get? What type of content, text or an image?  Is there a height value for `.inner`?  What happens if `.inner`'s height is initially taller than the view port height?

Comment: Marc if you read the upper comments u exactly know what what I mean , the content is text and image, and I change the size of content by percent, It cant be taller, I know it's possible, and also I knbow my problem can be dont via JS , but I want a css solution, I cant believe any css solution doesnt exist

Comment: just resize my fiddle and you get what I mean

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you need to set a maximal and/or minimal w/h ratio of the `outer`, which is not doable in CSS only.

Comment: did you resize the fiddle ? if you did you saw the inner div size changed based on percent, the outer div height is always 100% to cover the viewport or window, I want set a min-height for outer div, but not in pixel , exact to the size of the inner div, but inner div size changed on different window size, and I dont know how to set min-height, Look at the @Harry Comment, he fully got my problem

Comment: If that comment was directed to me, then, Yes, I did resize the fiddle and I know what your probles is. But there is no CSS-only solution for setting a w/h ratio.

Comment: does your issue even exist if you remove position absolute??

Comment: Looks like I have to take that back. But if position absolute stays, there really is no solution.

Comment: Just use image placeholder of the same ratio as your inner div, see my answer

Comment: the problem solved, the outer div should have min-height 100% and height: auto, with pure CSS

Comment: @CameronA without the position absolute, what's the issue if you just set outer div to height 100%?

Comment: I Updated the question if you see I told you can omit the position absolute

Comment: the problem is if I resize vertically the window height is always 100% if the windows is shorter than inner div, the inner div jump outside but outer div height stay 100%

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LmDNx/14/)

You can set `height` to `auto` and `min-height` to `100%`. That is, only if the `inner` div has static position.

```
.outer {
    height: auto;
    background:red;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.inner {
    background:blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto; /* or 0 if you want to maintain its position in the upper-left corner */
    padding-top: 30%;
}
```

Comment: wait, what's the issue if your inner div is not absolute? you can just set outer div to height 100% and there is no problem

Comment: @Huangism Not really, if you set height to 100% only, then it doesn't stretch with the inner when inner is over 100% of viewport.

Comment: oh i see it now, man if this question was structured better it would of been answered long time ago

Comment: check it http://jsfiddle.net/LmDNx/15/

it have problem if window is shorter than inner div what happend ?

Comment: Well you can always set the outer div to be position fixed, based on the example it works too http://jsfiddle.net/LmDNx/16/

Comment: thanks ,that's a good point, I know this question was very beginner for you :) but the answer is very important to me, that's why I started a bounty

Comment: __I doubt if it's _ok___ that after doing this, the body's height won't stretch more than the viewport's height anymore?!

Comment: It usually is not a problem on itself, unless you have something that relies on real body height. In the question itself, body is set to 100%, so the problem is already in the question.

However, since this answer is 8 years old, it would probably be different if written today. Eg. we now have viewport units that could be used in this case if we are talking about min height with regards to viewport: `min-height: 60vh`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, does setting both to `position: relative` and removing the `margin: auto` meet your requirement?

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
.outer {
    background:red;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    position: relative;
    background:blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;  /* required if you're using padding */
    width: 60%;
    padding-top: 30%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LmDNx/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
.outer {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.inner {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto; 
    padding-top: 30%;
}
```

**min-height attribute** can be used and it accepts value in %

Answer (score -1):

```
.outer {
    background:red;
}
.inner {
    background:blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 30%;
}
```