# Bootstrap two-column layout 100% height extra space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make two-column full-height layout with fixed sidebar width. To do this I'm using `display: table; display: table-cell;` method . Here is my code so far:

Html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header"> 
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="page-wrap">
    <div class="container">    
        <div class="page-sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">there'll be navigation</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="page-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus non?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
    margin: 0;
}

.page-wrap {
    height: 100%;
}

.page-wrap > .container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed; 
    height: 100%;
}

.page-sidebar {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ececec;
}

.page-sidebar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.page-content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4txrf/)

All seems works fine, but is one thing. Although, there is almost no content, there is extra space on the bottom of page, which make scrollbar is visible. What causes it, and how is best way to deal with it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

better to make .page-wrap class height auto
ex:

```
.page-wrap{
   height:auto
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4txrf/2/ But I want to have sidebar and content 100% height down to the bottom of page. If I set height to auto like you said, it won't work for me.

Comment: With more content in div it's height will also increase,if you want to extend it to bottom without scroll bar or extra space and with no content, make body height:auto and decrease container height,may be to 82%

Answer (score 1):

Sorry meant to post this as an answer. This should sort it for you.

[Body height 100% displaying vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989931/body-height-100-displaying-vertical-scrollbar)

Answer (score 0):

remove **height: 100%;** from html , body then scroll bar will be not visible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the implicit `margin` of `ul`

If you add

```
ul {    
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

then it will disappear: <kbd>[Running Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4txrf/1/)</kbd>

To deal with this kind of things, it would be better to reset HTML to the default behaviours everywhere with a **CSS Reset**, [like described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19542880/1654265).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, eventually setting `padding-bottom: 51px` (navbar height + 1px bottom border) for `body` do the trick, works like a charm :)