# How to exclude /project/struts/xhtml/styles.css while using <sx:head>

Tags: struts2, dojo

In my project when I add `<sx:head></sx:head>` it is including some required javascript and css( /project/struts/xhtml/styles.css ) files to implement Ajax. I don't want css files to be included (I have my own defined css) because it is changing my page format. 
How to do that?

Comment: use <sx:head theme="simple"></sx:head> . It will disable default css .

Comment: Just include required js w/o using `<sx:head>` tag.

Comment: @AleksandrM I don't know how to do that. Can you plz tell me the way

Comment: What do you mean? Copy them from generated html and paste into your page.

Comment: It is helping. But the dropdown box is using my css styles. Even though the generated html shows `<sx:autocompleter>` as `<select>`, that dropdown is not as I formatted it in css.

Comment: Then edit your own answer, add a running code snippet (the button beside the picture one) and reproduce the problem by posting the generated HTML and the CSS used. You are probably not using the right selectors, or other selectors have an higher specificity, or you are hitting some browser specific setting (each browsers has default settings, that's why [CSS Resets](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19542880/1654265) exist), or most likely you are trying to tweak a Select the wrong way: <select> are not easy to tweak (together with file inputs, checkboxes and radiobuttons).