# Cannot remove padding from div

Tags: html, css, struts2

I have a `<s:actionmessage />` that displays a message upon successful execution of an action.

**`success.jsp`**:

```
<s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
    <div class="messages justify">
        <s:actionmessage />
    </div>
</s:if>
```

**CSS:**

```
.messages {
    background-color: #80FF80;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 600px;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.messages li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.justify {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

By default, it appears `<s:actionmessage />`, displays a `<li>`, so I have modified the CSS to remove its default style.

But, there is still an uneven padding on the left of the div, even with setting to
`padding: 0; margin: 0;`.

How to make both sides even?

**EDIT: (Inspect Element)**

```
<div class="messages justify">
    <ul class="actionMessage">
        <li>
            <span>
                You have successfully changed your password. This is just to make the message long, so it will have to go to the second line of the div.
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: _displays a li_ means it has a parent `ul` or directly `.messages`

Comment: Hi, I added `.messages ul{padding:0}` but still the same.

Comment: Inspect the element and you'll see what is the issue.

Comment: I have added the inspect element into the post. I also modified the CSS by adding `.messages ul {padding: 0; margin: 0;}` and `.messages span {padding: 0; margin: 0;}`, but still the same.

Comment: `.actionMessage{padding:0;}` if not try with important `.actionMessage{padding:0 !important;}`

Comment: You can look at which element in the DOM has a padding and which CSS rule is applied. Then use CSS selector to override the rule.

Comment: @ohtph what happens if you put `*{padding:0}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is due to the default `padding-left` applied by browsers to the `<ul>` element.

There are many elements with default values, and they may vary between different browsers (and they do), for this reason you should load as first in the page, a CSS Reset, that is a special stylesheet used to erase any browser-specific default setting and ensure that the CSS rules that you will write will be rendered in the same way in every browser.

Take a look at this old but still good [List of CSS Reset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19542880/1654265).

By the way, @VitorinoFernandes solution is right (while the other is not, because it's applying the padding to the `<li>`, not to the `<ul>`), and this is a running example:

```css
.messages {
    background-color: #80FF80;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 600px;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.messages li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.justify {
    text-align: justify;
}

.nopadding{
   padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="messages justify">
    <ul class="actionMessage">
        <li>
            <span>
                You have successfully changed your password. This is just to make the message long, so it will have to go to the second line of the div.
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="messages justify">
    <ul class="actionMessage nopadding">
        <li>
            <span>
                You have successfully changed your password. This is just to make the message long, so it will have to go to the second line of the div.
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then you have a different HTML from the one shown, or you have a typo in CSS rules, or you have other CSS rules loaded after the above one that are overriding the setting (but it would be strange, this is 99.9% the default padding, so... I bet on the typo).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the CSS reset, I was unaware of such. :)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the `browsers` gives default `padding` for `ul`/`ol`

Try with this

```
.messages .actionMessage{
  padding:0;
}
```

if not try with !important

```
.messages .actionMessage{
  padding:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried both of the above. No changes. How mysterious this is haha.

Comment: that is too much mysterious buddy

Answer (score 1):

I just added `padding-right` to even it out:

```
.messages {
    background-color: #80FF80;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 600px;
    color: #000000;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.messages li {
    list-style: none;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
```

Doesn't look so bad.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add `!important` in your CSS `.message li` as

```
 .message li{
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;}
```

Comment: __!important__ is never the answer.

Comment: Hi, no changes occurred.