# Ognl Exception Class cast exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, jboss, ognl

I have production sever have a deployment of struts 2 app. It will running fine and have no changes is sent to server but some time it will gives following exception and app has been crashed and after restart it will again running fine . I am using struts 2.3.15.2 version . Please help me on this I have googled it for last 5 day and not found any solution .

```
INFO web.AppUpdateAction.fetchAppUpdateList(107) | Mobile os version iPhone
2013-10-24 02:07:33,320  WARN ognl.OgnlValueStack.warn(64) | Error setting expression 'IMEI' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@1d67244'
ognl.OgnlException: IMEI [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@1831114]
        at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:103)
        at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:162)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.ObjectAccessor.setProperty(ObjectAccessor.java:27)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2332)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.CompoundRootAccessor.setProperty(CompoundRootAccessor.java:78)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2332)
        at ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:127)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
        at ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:737)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:234)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:183)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:170)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setParameter(OgnlValueStack.java:148)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:318)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:231)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.i2c.choldermobile.framework.interceptors.AppControlParamterInterceptor.intercept(AppControlParamterInterceptor.java:65)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.i2c.choldermobile.framework.interceptors.MobileInstanceInterceptor.intercept(MobileInstanceInterceptor.java:65)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.i2c.choldermobile.framework.interceptors.CachingInterceptor.intercept(CachingInterceptor.java:40)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.i2c.choldermobile.framework.interceptors.ActivityLoggerInterceptor.intercept(ActivityLoggerInterceptor.java:72)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@1831114
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:891)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1293)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1494)
        at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:85)
        ... 64 more
/-- Encapsulated exception ------------\
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@1831114
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:891)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1293)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1494)
        at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:85)
        at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:162)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.ObjectAccessor.setProperty(ObjectAccessor.java:27)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2332)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.CompoundRootAccessor.setProperty(CompoundRootAccessor.java:78)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2332)
        at ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:127)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
        at ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:737)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:234)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:183)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:170)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setParameter(OgnlValueStack.java:148)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:318)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:231)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.i2c.choldermobile.framework.interceptors.AppControlParamterInterceptor.intercept(AppControlParamterInterceptor.java:65)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.i2c.choldermobile.framework.interceptors.MobileInstanceInterceptor.intercept(MobileInstanceInterceptor.java:65)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.i2c.choldermobile.framework.interceptors.CachingInterceptor.intercept(CachingInterceptor.java:40)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.i2c.choldermobile.framework.interceptors.ActivityLoggerInterceptor.intercept(ActivityLoggerInterceptor.java:72)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
\--------------------------------------/
2013-10-24 02:07:33,320  INFO interceptors.AppControlParamterInterceptor.intercept(42) | mobileOSVersion :6.1.3
2013-10-24 02:07:33,333  WARN ognl.OgnlValueStack.warn(64) | Error setting expression 'mobileApplicationId' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@a4196e'
ognl.OgnlException: mobileApplicationId [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@1e7f95c]
        at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:103)
        at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:162)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.ObjectAccessor.setProperty(ObjectAccessor.java:27)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2332)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.CompoundRootAccessor.setProperty(CompoundRootAccessor.java:78)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2332)
        at ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:127)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
        at ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:737)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:234)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:183)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:170)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setParameter(OgnlValueStack.java:148)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:318)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:231)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.i2c.choldermobile.framework.interceptors.AppControlParamterInterceptor.intercept(AppControlParamterInterceptor.java:65)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.i2c.choldermobile.framework.interceptors.MobileInstanceInterceptor.intercept(MobileInstanceInterceptor.java:65)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.i2c.choldermobile.framework.interceptors.CachingInterceptor.intercept(CachingInterceptor.java:40)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at com.i2c.choldermobile.framework.interceptors.ActivityLoggerInterceptor.intercept(ActivityLoggerInterceptor.java:72)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@1e7f95c
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor108.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:891)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1293)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1494)
        at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:85)
        ... 64 more
/-- Encapsulated exception ------------\
```

Following is my code AppControlParameterInterceptor code.

```
final ActionContext context = actionInvocation.getInvocationContext();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_RESPONSE);

String mobileAppliationId = request.getParameter(Constants.MOBILE_APPLICATION_ID_KEY);
LGR.info("mobileAppliationId :" + mobileAppliationId );
String mobileVersionNo = request.getParameter("mobileApplicationVersion");
LGR.info("mobileApplicationVersion :" + mobileVersionNo );
String mobileOSVersion = request.getParameter("mobileOSVersion");
LGR.info("mobileOSVersion :" + mobileOSVersion );

if(!StringUtils.isNullOrEmptyString(mobileOSVersion)){
    mobileOSVersion = mobileOSVersion.split(" ")[0];
}
return actionInvocation.invoke();

if(StringUtils.isNullOrEmptyString(mobileAppliationId) 
        || StringUtils.isNullOrEmptyString(mobileOSVersion)){
    LGR.info("Missing info as mobileAppliationId or mobileVersionNo or mobileOSVersion is either not provided or invalid ");
    return Constants.APPLICATION_INFO_MISSING;
}
else{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list =Class.getData();
    String key = mobileAppliationId+"_"+mobileVersionNo+"_"+mobileOSVersion;    


    String data = list.get(1).get(key);
    if(!StringUtils.isNullOrEmptyString(data)){
        response.setHeader(Constants.X_PA, data);
    }else{
        contorlParams = controlParamsList.get(0).get(Constants.B_CP);
        response.setHeader(Constants.X_PA, data);
    }
    return actionInvocation.invoke();
}
```

public class AppControlParamterInterceptor  implements Interceptor {

```
private static final Logger LGR = Logger.getLogger(AppControlParamterInterceptor .class);

@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
    LGR.info("********* [ControlParamsInterceptor] - Interceptor – intercept ***********");
    LGR.info("ControlParams Interceptor Called");
    final ActionContext context = actionInvocation.getInvocationContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_RESPONSE);

    String mobileAppliationId = request.getParameter(Constants.MOBILE_APPLICATION_ID_KEY);
    LGR.info("mobileAppliationId :" + mobileAppliationId );
    String mobileVersionNo = request.getParameter("mobileApplicationVersion");
    LGR.info("mobileApplicationVersion :" + mobileVersionNo );
    String mobileOSVersion = request.getParameter("mobileOSVersion");
    LGR.info("mobileOSVersion :" + mobileOSVersion );


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> controlParamsList = CacheManager.getControlParams();
        String key = mobileAppliationId+"_"+mobileVersionNo+"_"+mobileOSVersion;    


        String contorlParams = controlParamsList.get(1).get(key);
        if(!StringUtils.isNullOrEmptyString(contorlParams)){
            response.setHeader(Constants.X_MOBILE_APP_PARAMETER, contorlParams);
        }else{
            contorlParams = controlParamsList.get(0).get(Constants.BASE_CONTRL_PARAM_KEY);
            response.setHeader(Constants.X_MOBILE_APP_PARAMETER, contorlParams);
        }
        return actionInvocation.invoke();

}
```

}

Comment: what are the values expected and passed in those fields - IMEI and mobileApplicationId?

Comment: mobileApplicationId="achieveCardBc" and IMEI = "548956215478549"

Comment: post your entire interceptor, not only the doIntercept please. And btw the first `return actionInvocation.invoke();` is placed in a really weird place...

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a List of Strings (`'[Ljava.lang.String;@1d67244'` : the L means List) to parameters named `IMEI` and `mobileApplicationId`.

From the names, they don't seem Lists to me.

**If they are** `String`s , and **not** `List<String>`s, then this is what is causing your ClassCastException, and it does mean that (sometimes) you are sending two parameters with the same name from the JSP to the Action (if you send two parameters with the same name, they'll become a `List<String>` and will search for this kind of Setter), probably due to some JavaScript mess.

EDIT: thinking about it more deeply, your AppControlParameterInterceptor is probably [running in some thread-unsafeness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13624381/1654265) issue. Post your Interceptor code to be sure.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it. Actually we are sending our request through mobile as post parameters and i have make sure it has no dual parameter with same name and we want to reproduce it again but not able to reproduce such type of exception.

Comment: AppControlParameterInterceptor is not running in any other thread but I have another interceptor which is used for logging purpose and it running in a separate user thread.

Comment: Actually I am not able to reproduce this exception again. I am not sure how it will product because I send multiple parameter with same name but it works. I am not sure how it will happens again

Comment: @AndreaLigios [please give support to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234497/how-to-making-full-height-on-every-screen-for-section-or-div-inside-body) sorry to call from here

Comment: amamd: where is `contorlParams` defined ? I asked you for full interceptor code, not only doIntercept body. If that field is a class field, than we've found your Thread-Unsafety issue ;)

Comment: @Meow your Bat-Signal made me laugh hard :D

Comment: No contorlParams is not the class field. @AndreaLigios have you any idea what my doing wrong because there is not major update on my production server and every thing was working fine but now its weird for us.

Comment: What is CacheManager ? (I thought I had already asked that, but the comment has not been correctly posted, evidenlty)